# Javascript: Refresh current page after event change $_SESSION in a other page

Tags: javascript, php

I need help for a subtlety.
I created a multilingual site without changing using the same php file, I just modify its content.
For this I use sessions.
So I configured 2 buttons: FR and EN which change the language.
I go through another php file.
With this code it works if I manually reload the page.
But if I use:

```
location.reload(true);
```

it doesn't work and i want to automatically reload the page without user intervention.
Does anyone have the solution?
Thanking you,
Regards,

my code index.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['lang']) == false){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link href="_style/style-master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <script type='text/javascript'>
    function setSession(lang) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "change.php?lang=" + lang, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        //here reload and refresh page after execute code in change.php
    }
</script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <?php
    if($_SESSION['lang'] == "fr"){
        echo "<body>";
        echo "<p>Page française</p>";
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:setSession('en')\"><input type='submit' value='EN'></a>";
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:setSession('fr')\"><input type='submit' value='FR'></a>";
        echo "</body>";
    } else{
        echo "<body>";
        echo "<p>English page</p>";
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:setSession('en')\"><input type='submit' value='EN'></a>";
        echo "<a href=\"javascript:setSession('fr')\"><input type='submit' value='FR'></a>";
        echo "</body>";
    }
    ?>
</html>
```

change.php :

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['lang']))
    {
    $lang = $_REQUEST['lang'];
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code reloads the `index.php` immediately and doesn't even wait for the request (to `change.php`) to be sent.

You can handle the [onreadystatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) event of `XMLHttpRequest`, specifically you're looking for state 2, which is [HEADERS_RECEIVED](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState), or any later state.

When the PHP script sends headers, it means it already finished executing (and set the session). And you can safely reload the index page.

```
function setSession(lang) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState === 2) {
            //here reload and refresh page after execute code in change.php
            location.reload(true);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "change.php?lang=" + lang, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Indeed it works, I suspected that it was a subtlety like that but I do not know the function.

Thanks